# search suggestions problem android

Tags: android

Well i've been looking at Android's Documentation and i don't seem to understand how they can query a database to show suggestions while the user is typing. Can you guys tell me what listener to implement? I tried `onContentChanged()` but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: to be more clear, i got stuck in that example because i dont know how to implement this: android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MyCustomSuggestionProvider">
what is MyCustomSuggestionProvider? a class ? What should this class have in it, a database connection to run search queries that return a list with suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but it should be a class which implements the CustomSuggestionProvider. And the namespace.classname should be use as searchSuggestAuthority.